# ASP.NET MVC ajax call security issue

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc3 to develop application.

I protect my pages agaings CSRF by aniforgerytoken.

Imagine that i have Delete button above the datagrid. If user clicks on button, ajax call will post id's of selected items to e.g Countries/Delete action.

Problem is, that user can try to change request's id's (when he look into source code page, he will se $.post(...)), so he can delete countries, which was not selected (in the worst case, for which he hasn't privileges to delete them)

How can i protect my pages againts this? I don't wanna check on delete action, if user really has rights to delete items.

I hear about some ajax call hashing, but didn't found any useful tutorials or something to do that in MVC.

Comment: "_check on delete action, if user really has rights to delete items._" This is the answer. Anything related to authentication, authorization, validation, or security in general _must_ be completed on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to do anything on the client side. Instead, you should check on the server side that the user has privileges to delete the countries that were selected for deletion, and only delete those that they have privileges to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a post use the below

```
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

If you are using a get use

```
[Authorize]
```

You can also use this custom attribute below

```
public class HttpAjaxRequestAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            throw new Exception("This action " + methodInfo.Name + " can only be called via an Ajax request");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, decorate your action as below

```
[Authorize]
[HttpAjaxRequest]

public ActionResult FillCity(int State)
{
    //code here
}
```

Remember to "Mark/Tick" if this solve your problem.

Comment: if its not useful for the OP, it can be useful for other